# How can I change the background color of a Main Activity by using spinner while clicking a button in the Second Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to change the background color of Main activity by using spinner in second Activity. I have already created one button and it goes to second activity and in this second activity I have created spinner which consist of which color should be in the main activity. After choosing the color, the button I created will change the background color and will be back to first activity.

Comment: Make a model of the colour class, create colour object, get and set the colour object accordingly. Therefore, in your second activity, you'll create a colour object and set the desired colour on setOnItemSelectedListener. When you get back to the MainActivity, get the object and set the colour accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need the ActivityForResult behavior.

- You use `startActivityForResult` to fire the Intent from your first activity to your second, along with a request code.
- You use an Intent and `setResult` to send data from your second activity back to your first.
- You override `onActivityResult` in your fist activity to get and use your data.

Sample code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int PICK_COLOR_REQUEST = 1001;

    ...

    private void pickColor() {
        Intent pickColorIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(pickColorIntent, PICK_COLOR_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_COLOR_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int color = data.getIntExtra("color");
            /* use the color */
        }
    }
}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    ...

    private void onColorPicked(int color) {
        Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
        dataIntent.putExtra("color", color);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot!

Comment: @SemihAltaş great to hear, if you want, mark my answer as correct